# Why doesn't %a format specifier display NaN payloads?

Tags: c, printf

I use `%a` for outputting coefficients of fitted polynomials. Sometimes they go bad or denormal (but in this case it was due to a weird compiler fault). `%f` and `%d` report them as "nan" or "inf" (fair enough) but so does `"%a"` when it could just as easily display the hexadecimal representation of the actual mantissa. This can potentially contain useful information.

Hardware generated true nans have only a few distinct values whereas nans caused by over enthusiastic optimisers can have all sorts of peculiar values. Only experts are likely to use %a in anger so it might just as well display the thing in raw binary exponent form or alternately `0x1.xxxxxxnan`.

Whilst it isn't much of a problem to print out the raw value in hexadecimal it took me by surprise that `%a` lost information when it processes a nan for output to the terminal. I always thought its purpose was to be able to represent in hexadecimal any floating point bit pattern saved to a file in human readable form and then reloaded into an FP variable on demand.

Comment: "Only experts are likely to use `%a` in anger" or at least desperation. If you have flaky floating point code it might be useful, but otherwise, if you're getting NaN or unexpected Inf then you have a debugging problem.

Comment: @tadman Actually I had neither. It was an aggressive compiler optimising fault and if I had been able to see the nan payload I would have realised very much sooner that it was a loop counter variable posing as a nan. I had assumed it was bad numeric code at first (because most times it is!).  %a has entirely legitimate uses when you want to save coefficients in human and exact machine readable form to include in other programs.

Comment: the quesiton is `Why doesn't %a format specifier display NaN payloads?` . It doesn't, because it is not required to. It's hard to answer why something doesn't exist and never existed. It doesn't, because it is not there. No one implemented it, no one standarized it.

Comment: It's printing them as required by the standard: *A double argument representing an infinity or NaN is converted in the style of an f or F conversion specifier.* Which in turn says *A double argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles `[-]nan` or `[-]nan(n-char-sequence)` -- which style, and the meaning of any n-char-sequence, is implementation-defined.*

Comment: So maybe bug the author(s) of your implementation to switch to the second form and include the data you want to see in the n-char-sequence, if they're receptive to suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the `%a` (or `%A`) format specifier when the corresponding argument is infinity or NaN is as you have described ***because the Standard says so***.

From [this Draft C17 Standard](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf):

> #### 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions
>
> …
> **Description**
> …
> 8      The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

Then, in the second paragraph describing the `a` and `A` specifiers:

> A **`double`** argument representing an infinity or NaN is converted in
> the style of an `f` or `F` conversion specifier.

Finally, in the paragraph describing the `f` and `F` specifiers:

> A **`double`** argument representing an infinity is converted in one of the styles `[-]inf` or `[-]infinity` — which style is implementation-defined.
> A **`double`** argument representing a NaN is converted in one of the styles [-]nan or [-]nan *(n-char-sequence)* — which style, and the meaning of
> any *n-char-sequence*, is implementation-defined. The `F` conversion
> specifier produces `INF`, `INFINITY`, or `NAN` instead of `inf`, `infinity`,
> or `nan`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a shame that more compilers do not implement the nan(n-char-sequence) form (particularly so in %a output). In ordinary floating point work Nan/Inf is plenty good enough but when things have gone haywire being able to see the difference between a true hardware generated Nan double and the ~2^52-6 other possibilities caused by rogue code can be rather useful.

Comment: NaN has some implementation problems, as the standard (the IEEE-754) states that the exponent part must be all ones, and the significand must be != 0 (all zeros reserved for `+-inf`) and so, are many different values (the standard only talks about silent NaNs and verbose NaNs, based on the most signifiant bit of the significand, but everything else is up to you to define as you whish)